React-Router-Dom File not Fount after build
This is my App.jsx:
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Callback from "./pages/callback";
import Home from "./pages/home";
import Logout from "./pages/logout";
import HomePage from "./pages/homepage";
import Moderation from "./pages/moderation";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/callback" element={<Callback />} />
        <Route path="/logout" element={<Logout />} />
        <Route path="/moderation" element={<Moderation />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App

After I built the app with npm run build in Vite, the router does not longer work. Only the HomePage is available, the other routes are not working (File not found).
I tried multiple solutions I found, like using sth like the HashRouter but I didn't figure out how to use it correctly and I only got blank pages with it.
This is my nginx webserver configuration:
server {
  server_name mydomain.xyz;

  root /var/www/website;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
    expires -1;
    # access_log logs/static.log; # I don't usually include a static log
  }

  location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    expires 1y;
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
  }

  # Any route containing a file extension (e.g. /devicesfile.js)
  location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  # Any route that doesn't have a file extension (e.g. /devices)
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

    listen myserverip:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = mydomain.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen myserverip:80 default_server;
  server_name mydomain.xyz;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}


Hi and welcome on StackOverflow. Please, include some details like: how are you running the built application? Via a webserver or directly opening the index.html? If via a webserver, is there a configuration file?

Hi, I updated my question above with my nginx config. I found a configuration online that should have fixed the routing error. but now everyt ime I open a route I just open the homepage

Tried with your code and it all works, is there some other relevant code or info to share? Like, e.g.: are you navigating directly or through a react-created link? If it's the second case, can you post the react code where you render the links? Also, try to remove the last server block from nginx config; it seems redundant to me
